# HTML Codes are doesn't work in bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a bootstrap table with filters and search options are on.
But i can't use HTML/PHP codes in table when i use "data-toggle="table"

[image]

I've tried the update bootstrap versions its didn't work.

When i remove "data-toggle="table" codes are starts to working.

I greatly appreciate your help

Here is my codes;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" >
    
    <head>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>KVK Teknik Servis Hizmet Verilen Modeller Tablosu</title>
    
    
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css'>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.min.css'>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://rawgit.com/vitalets/x-editable/master/dist/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css'>
    
    
    
    </head>
    
    <body>
     <div class="container">
    
    
      <div id="toolbar">    
      </select>
     </div>
    
     <table id="table" 
     data-toggle="table"
     data-search="true"
     data-filter-control="true" 
     data-show-export="true"
     data-click-to-select="true"
     class="table-responsive">
    
     <thead>
      <tr>
       <th data-field="state" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Marka</th>
       <th data-field="tip" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Tip</th>
       <th data-field="prenom" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Model</th>
       <th data-field="date" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Bölge</th>
       <th data-field="examen" data-filter-control="input" data-sortable="true">Yetki</th>   
       <th data-field="uzman" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Ürün Uzmanı</th>
       <th data-field="destek" data-filter-control="select" data-sortable="true">Teknik Destek</th>
       <th data-field="note" data-sortable="true">Link</th>
       <th data-field="bilgi" data-sortable="true">Button</th>
      </tr>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
    
      <tr><td>Asus</td>
       <td>Tablet</td>
       <td>TP200SA Transformer Book Flip</td>
       <td>KARTAL</td><td>Level 1, Anakart Değişimi, DOA, DAP</td>
       <td>Tuba BAKIR ILGAZ</td>
       <td>Emre DIĞIŞ</td>
       <td><a href="https://www.google.com">Sample Link</a></td>
       <td><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button>/td>
      </tr>
    
     </tbody>
    </table>
    </div>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.10.0/bootstrap-table.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/editable/bootstrap-table-editable.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.js'></script>
    <script src='http://rawgit.com/hhurz/tableExport.jquery.plugin/master/tableExport.js'></script>
    <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.9.1/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.js'></script>
    
    
    
    <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You made a typo. `</button>/td>` is missing a `<`. (Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo).

Comment: Corrected the typo, still. problem exists.

Answer (score -1):

```html
USE THIS:

<tbody>
<tr data-index="0">
<td style="">Asus</td>
<td style="">Tablet</td>
<td style="">TP200SA Transformer Book Flip</td>
<td style="">KARTAL</td>
<td style="">Level 1, Anakart Değişimi, DOA, DAP</td>
<td style="">Tuba BAKIR ILGAZ</td>
<td style="">Emre DIĞIŞ</td>
<td style=""><a href="https://www.google.com">Sample Link</a></td>
<td style=""><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary</button></td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Why? What did you change and why should it solve the problem? Is your recommendation to remove the JavaScript and CSS?

Comment: No, just replace the tbody contents from this. And keep everything as it is. Also seems you've incomplete "select" tag, please fix them as well

Comment: Problem still exist.When CSS/JS styles loaded its happens again.
When i disable search option, codes strats working.